# After Server reboot integrated authentication no longer works with IIS Site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, iis-7.5, windows-authentication

My server which hosts my IIS site has just rebooted, now when i navigate to my internal site, im getting a 401 challenge, it should be windows integrated. it doesnt accept credentials either.

below is the current config, it all worked prior to the reboot and i havent changed any code since. any ideas?

Thanks

webconfig

```
<system.web>
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-GB" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="true" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
```

IIS Settings

```
Authentication
Anyon: Enabled
ASP.net Imper Enabled
Windows Auth Enabled
```

Application Pool

```
.net 4.9
Managed pipeline intergrated
identity applicationpoolidentity
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this. my server needed an SPN adding

Comment: Could you please add some details on **how** you fixed this problem? Just saying "SPN adding" doesn't mean much.